# How to Run Container on a Specified Disk?

Tags: docker, containers

Normally we would run container by using the following command:

```
Docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Is there any option to specify where to run the container (like on which disk or partition)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean where the container data/layers will be stored?

The layers are all inside /var/lib/docker/(aufs)

It's possible for you to mount a different larger/faster partition into this folder, but this is for the entire docker platform.  if you are careful, you can mount the partition for a particular docker container.

It would be better if you would use "docker run -v folder:mount point" flag, since you can mount specific host folders as external volumes inside the container.

Both these can help you spread data over different partitions/disks.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I guess my question was not clear to you. My question is, I want to know if there is a way to specify the path to the containers to be created on run-time? like docker run <image-name> <layer-path>

Comment: i see now.  that's a good question.  i wonder what would happen if you did exactly that.  `docker run -v outside_path:/ image_name`

Comment: No it ll not work.because -v is just for sharing folders between container and host and to attach devices

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a container specific option.

However, you can bind-mount (or create a symlink) a particular disk or partition to '/var/lib/docker'. This will make all the container storage to be on that partition.

If you want the container storage to be on multiple partitions, LVM is an option. 
You can setup a volume group that spans multiple partitions. You can then ask the Docker daemon to create a thinly provisioned logical volume in one of these volume groups to be used as storage.

The following link provides more information : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-host/7/getting-started-with-containers/chapter-7-managing-storage-with-docker-formatted-containers

Also, using a union mount like OverlayFS could be another solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs